# Realtime notification using signalR

Tags: dashboard, signalr

I am new to SignalR. I am hoping to integrate SignalR to send notification in dashboard (i.e. latest applications created by staff) so that new applications will be shown without refreshing the dashboard. Applications should be fetched from a database (sql server) and notified to the dashboard. Is there any sample that I can look in to and take some idea how to start on this?  Any help is highly appreciated.
Regards
Samitha

Answer (score 4):

Sounds cut and dry. You want to create a [`Hub`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) which your dashboard clients can connect to to receive updates. Then either the Hub itself could have a monitoring routine (e.g. background thread that is watching some stream of events from some external resource) that is pushing out updates to the connected clients.

Alternatively you could go with a better separation and just have the `Hub` be "dumb" and move the monitoring/notification off into another background process which just connects to the `Hub` like any other client and just pushes its notifications to the other clients through the `Hub`.

I would highly recommend just reading [the Wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) and taking a look at some of the samples that come with the SignalR solution.